# UWP - Cache local video

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm creating a carousel with a couple of panels containing a 2MB video as the background. The video is present in the project folder with **Build Action** as **Content** and **Copy to Output Directory** as **Do not copy**. Now the problem I'm facing is that there is a lag between when the carousel panel gets navigated to and when the background video starts playing. The time of the lag varies. I know this is because of the load on the CPU. Sometimes it's so minute that the user might not notice it, other times it's almost a second. I know we can cache images but I was unable to find a way to cache the video so that there is no lag present.

I'm deeply sorry that I cannot share the code with you.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `MediaSource.CreateFromUri` to load video. This might take a little 
more time than you read from memory. So you can read the video file to memory first, then use `MediaSource.CreateFromStream` or `MediaSource.CreateFromStreamReference`.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache and prepare the media source before use by creating it however you want, then calling `myMediaSource.OpenAsync()`.

You can also pre-prepare the MediaPlayer before hand with no UI in your code / viewmodel, then use MediaPlayerPresenter to display it on the UI